# Application not opening with url as in the war name when running in eclipse server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am having maven web project with name XYZwebApp and i generated war inside that as ABCWebApp while running the project as (Right click -->Run As--> Run on Server)
it shows the XYZwebApp in the configured AddorRemove window

And also after running the application its opening the 404 page with the url http://localhost:9090/ABCWebApp/
But if i am changing the url as http://localhost:9090/XYZWebApp/ its working fine.

Above thing is happening in Jboss server in eclipse, i need application should be working fine with this url http://localhost:9090/ABCWebApp/

But the above problem is not happing when i start the server in cmd and pasting the war in webapps folder is working fine.

Confused by this issue, please help me why it is happening and how to resolve.

Give comments if you need more input.

i added path as ABCWebApp doesnt work and
i changed name as ABCWebApp doesnt work.

My pom.xml is

```
<artifactId>XYZwebApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ABCWebApp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>ABCWebApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <path>/ABCWebApp</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you configured the context root correctly? Eclipse>WarProject>Properties>Web>Context Root

Comment: context path with name ABCWebApp  only still problem exists

Answer (score 0):

Double-click on the tomcat server on which you are deploying you application in Servers view, go to modules tab and check the *Path* for the application is correct as you need. If it is not then select and edit the path, save it and re-run the application (Right click -->Run As--> Run on Server).

**Edit 1:**
Modules tab and path to edit can be found highlighted in below image, 
[image: Tomcat Modules]

Comment: Hi Surya, sorry for the trouble the problem is happening only in jboss server in eclipse

Comment: Can u put the values here of _artifactId_ and _finalName_ from _build_ tag from pom.xml?